# Django is ignoring my TestCase fixtures

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I've got Django 1.4. In my test.py, I've got the requisite TestCase import:

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

To isolate the issue, I've added the line:

```
fixtures = ['westeros']
```

to the default example test case, i.e.

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['westeros']

    def test_basic_addition(self):
        """
        Tests that 1 + 1 always equals 2.
        """
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 2)
```

Using django-admin.py dumpdata, I created a fixture file called "westeros" in my customers/fixtures directory, where "customers" is an app that is listed in settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

When I run the test, at any verbosity, Django simply ignores the fixture and passes the `test_basic_addition` test. No error, no fixture loading. It's as if the TestCase import isn't there. Any ideas on what could be wrong or how to debug this?

Comment: Have you tried with loaddata? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to omit the extension when defining `fixtures` as you have done, i.e.

```
fixtures = ['westeros']
```

However, the fixture file itself must have the extension that corresponds to its serializer e.g `westeros.json`, `westeros.json.zip` or `westeros.xml` for json, zipped json or xml respectively.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you. That was the problem. It worked when I renamed westeros to westeros.json. I'm still mystified why Django remains completely silent on the matter. Even though the fixture is now loading, it still says nothing, even on verbosity 3.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `westeros` file located?

It needs to either be in a `fixtures` directory inside an app or in the dir specified by `FIXTURE_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file

You can run with tests with `verbosity=2` to get full output.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/django-admin/#test

Is your fixtures file named `westeros` ? or does it have a file extension?

Django will fail silently on fixture loads as you see. (at least up until 1.3, I haven't used fixtures in new 1.4 version yet).  But you are not actually testing if the fixtures are loading.
Throw in a `self.assertGreater(YourModel.objects.all(), 0)` or somethign to verify that there are no objects, or drop in a debbuger and start querying some of your models.

Comment: Thanks. Answers: (1) the "westeros" file is located in the customers/fixtures dir, where customers is one of my installed apps; (2) I've run with verbosity 2 (and 3); (3) yep I have verified the fixture isn't being loaded (just didn't show that in my question).